# Ambiguous column name error during select operation

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am getting the following error:

> Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 3 Ambiguous column name 'NUM_0'.

```
SELECT BPR_0, BPAPAY_0, BPYNAM_0, BPYADDLIG_0, NUM_0 -- and so on
  FROM PROD.SINVOICE, PROD.SINVOICED
  WHERE SINVOICE.NUM_0 = SINVOICED.NUM_0
```

[image]

Comment: Since both tables have a column named `NUM_0` you need to specify which table to select from: I.e. `SELECT ... SINVOICE.NUM_0 ... FROM ... WHERE ...`.

Answer (score 1):

Qualify column name with table `alise` explicitly :

```
select sin.col, . . ., sind.col, . . ., c.col, . . .
from prod.sininvoice sin inner join
     prod.sininvoiced sind
     on sind.num_0 = sin_num_0 inner join
     prod.customer c 
     on . . .;
```

Comment: Thank you so much. One more question. I have to add one more table, which is the customer table. How can I do that.               "SELECT PROD.SINVOICE.BPR_0, PROD.SINVOICE.BPAPAY_0, PROD.SINVOICE.BPYNAM_0, PROD.SINVOICE.BPYADDLIG_0, PROD.SINVOICE.BPYADDLIG_2, PROD.SINVOICED.REP1_0, PROD.SINVOICED.REP2_0, PROD.SINVOICED.GROPRI_0
from PROD.SINVOICE INNER JOIN 
 PROD.SINVOICED 
 ON PROD.SINVOICED.NUM_0 = PROD.SINVOICE.NUM_0                                                                                                The third table is the customer table. That have the customer information.

Comment: @user10123643. . . Again do one more `JOIN`.

Answer (score 0):

Since Column "NUM_0" exists in both SINVOICE and SINVOICED tables,you need to specify the column with using alias.
For example SINVOICE.NUM_O or SINVOICED.NUM_O in you select statement depending upon from which table you want this column value.

Answer (score 0):

use `Alias`properly

Example

```
SELECT o.OrderID, o.OrderDate, c.CustomerName
FROM Customers AS c, Orders AS o
WHERE c.CustomerName="Around the Horn" AND c.CustomerID=o.CustomerID;
```

For Your case

```
select t1.col1,t1.col2 ....t1.coln from yourtable t1
inner join yourtable t2 on t1.num0=t2.num0
```